# I'm trying to make a java array code

Tags: java, arrays

i'm trying to build a code for different actions in arrays with different methods (Constructors) but i cannot seem to find a way to link them...I've made a array with 100 elements and a random variable to fill it....i'd like to know how to get my random elements from the first methods to the second one to make the comparing.... and also i'd like to not include in the 0 element in the random generator..any help?

this is my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class prova1{
    public int min;

    public void tabele(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int d;
        int e[]= new int[100];
        for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++){
            d=r.nextInt(100);
            e[i]=d;
            System.out.println(e[i]);
        }
    }
    public void emin(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int d;
        int e[]=new int[100];
        for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++){
            d=r.nextInt(100);
            e[i]=d;
            if(e[i]<min){
                min=e[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Vlera me e vogel eshte: " +min);

    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        prova1 prova = new prova1();
        prova.tabele();
        prova.emin();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the array from `tabele` to a local variable and send it as parameter to `emin`

```
import java.util.*;

public class prova1 {
    public int min;

    public int[] tabele() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int d;
        int e[]= new int[100];
        for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++){
            d=r.nextInt(99) + 1;
            e[i]=d;
            System.out.println(e[i]);
        }

        return e;
    }

    public void emin(int[] e) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int d;
        for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++) {
            if(e[i]<min) {
                min=e[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Vlera me e vogel eshte: " +min);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        prova1 prova = new prova1();
        int[] arr = prova.tabele();
        prova.emin(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm still a little confused...the elements in the "emin method" are the same as in the "tabele method"?

Comment: @RediRamaj Yes. The array `e` is being populated with `int` elements in `tabele`. `tabele` returns this array to `main`, and `main` sends it to `emin` as parameter.

Comment: could you help me with the random option please? can a number be excluded when generating different numbers?

Comment: @RediRamaj what do you mean? you want all the numbers except one (say 5) or array without repeting  numbers?

Comment: in my case..i'd like all numbers 1-99 except from 0

Comment: @RediRamaj try 'r.nextInt(99) + 1;'

Comment: I've tried ,but if i want to find the minimal element its still 0 and not 1...or how can i generate numbers 11-99 and excluding 0-10?

Comment: @RediRamaj The formula to generate random number in range is `r.nextInt(maxValue - minvalue + 1) + minvalue`. For range 1-99 its `d = r.nextInt(99 - 1 + 1) + 1;` or `d = r.nextInt(99) + 1;`. For other ranges just put the numbers you want in the correct places.

Comment: also for the code u showed me last day...the number generated in the first method aren't the same as the one generated at the second..because when i try to get the whole sum of the number it print a different value?